# How to check the end of line using Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have searched similar questions, but none helped.

Consider a file :

> hi how are you?
>   where were you?

I want to do few operations after the end of every line. If I use `next()` it wont tell me when I have reached the end of the first line.

Also I have seen `hasNextLine()` but it only tells me if there exists another line or not.

Comment: do you have one and only one question mark (?) at the end of each line?

Comment: @niculare hehe..no..it may change.If that was the case i know would be simple.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider using more than one Scanner, one to get each line, and the other to scan through each line after you've received it. The only caveat I must give is that you must be sure to close the inner Scanner after you're done using it. Actually you will need to close *all* Scanners after you're done using them, but especially the inner Scanners since they can add up and waste resources.

e.g.,

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = fileScanner.nextLine();

  Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
  while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    String token = lineScanner.next();
    // do whatever needs to be done with token
  }
  lineScanner.close();
  // you're at the end of the line here. Do what you have to do.
}
fileScanner.close();
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same way, but thought might some simple functions will help..cause this is time consuming.Thanks +1

Comment: @yoohoo: I'm not sure how it's time consuming as it's only a few lines of code and it runs quite fast. You're welcome, BTW.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hehe time consuming i mean w.r.t CPU stuff.If there are a lot of lines, time consumption will be directly proportional.Isn't it?

Comment: @yoohoo: no, not at all. The only thing really time consuming in the code above is disk I/O access, and the processing that is done after the read is trivial compared to this. I think that you're worrying about exactly the wrong thing.

Comment: overcomplicated, keep it simple, use scanner and hasNextLine and nextLine

Comment: It's separating by space! I need to separate on new line.

Comment: @vishvavijay: re-look at the code -- it's separating by *both* which were the requirements of the original post

Answer (score 2):

You can use Scanner and the method you mentioned:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("your_file"));
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            // do your things here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the text line by line and split each line in tokens using `String.split()` method. This way you know when one line has ended and also have all the tokens on each line:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty())
        continue;
    // do whatever processing at the end of each line
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.isEmpty())
            continue;
        // do whatever processing for each token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant or too late when i read this. I am relatively new to Java but this seemed to work for me when i encountered a similar problem. I just used a DO-WHILE loop with a End of file specifier denoted by a simple string.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;`enter code here`

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String eof = "";

        do {
            String in = input.nextLine();
            name.add(in);
            eof = input.findInLine("//");
        } while (eof == null);

        System.out.println(name);
     }
}
```