# How to stop reading from a file by the end of a line in java

Tags: java, netbeans, integer

so using Scanner I need to read from a file that contains a list of integers. It has a bunch of lines and I need to stop reading by the end of each line and store it in an integer array.[This is what I currently have, What do I need to change to get this working?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvzSj.png)

[This is what the file I'm reading from looks like][2]

[This is what my output is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCkVp.png)

Comment: How do i tell the program to stop reading the numbers when it reaches the end of the line

Comment: all help appreciated

Comment: Please post the code, not as a picture.

Comment: `hasNext()` and/or `hasNextLine()` methods return false when you reach the end of file.

Comment: "What do i need to change to get this working?" - Isn't it working as intended? If so, in what way? What errors/wrong results do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
 at FileProcessor.main(FileProcessor.java:48)

Comment: This is the error i get when trying to print the array "anArray"

Comment: 23 13 -34 56 22
12

81 19 27
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
15 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 15 1 9 10 11 12 13 14
-2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -15 -1 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 a 6 7 8
-2147483648
-2147483648 2147483647

Comment: These are the numbers i'm reading but there is lines between every couple of them

Comment: So what do i need to change to make my program read the first line of integers, store it and (process it) and then do the same thing for the following one

Comment: I think, here you can find what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183761/how-to-check-the-end-of-line-using-scanner, if you want to read integers, just change the **String token = lineScanner.next();** line in that code. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the end of line using Scanner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183761/how-to-check-the-end-of-line-using-scanner)

Comment: i looked at that code but its not working for me