# How to use the hasNext() and next() methods

Tags: java, string, loops, java.util.scanner

My goal is to read and print the words separately from standard input, without having to store them in an array or list.

I want this:

input: sun moon cloud

output:
sun moon cloud (each word in a different line)

The following program keep waiting after printing "cloud". I don't know what the problem is

`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RandomWord{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String palavra;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(s.hasNext()){
            palavra = s.next();
            System.out.println(palavra);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Define _last given word_.

Comment: Well, your loop condition is "cannot read another word", so the loop keeps looping until you end the input. As long as you type words, it will not stop. _When_ _do_ you _want_ your program to stop?

Comment: I expect a single line containing words, and I want the program to stop after printing the last word on the line

Comment: use .readLine()

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183761/how-to-check-the-end-of-line-using-scanner

Comment: Press `ctrl-d` after you entered the last word, it will close the input. Java cannot know if a second line will be entered if you don't close the input

Answer (score 1):

You continuously reading the scanner.
You have to read by scanner out of loop. For example 3 times invoking s.next().
Or create some loop end condition, for example text, "END".

If you pass all words in one line use .readLine()

Comment: When would you close the input stream in this scenario?

Comment: There is no clean way to do that. Only way is make dirty if and for example close loop for some particular string

Comment: What is a dirty if? How would it improve OP's code?

Comment: Keeping logic in ifs and comparing Strings is bad for OOP purpose.

This code can be exit from loop for example if user pass "END" string, or it could be just end loop, or 3 invokes s.next()

Comment: @f1sh what is OP code?

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  In this question, that's user B612.

Answer (score 0):

A call to the `Scanner.hasNext` will block if it is waiting for user input.

It's useful for when you want a continuous input from the user.

Here is how to accomplish your task.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strings = s.nextLine().split(" +");
    for (String string : strings)
        System.out.println(string);
}
```

Output

```
sun
moon
cloud
```

The names `hasNext` and `next` are somewhat convoluted in the Java context.

An iterator also uses this terminology, as a way to gather data from a source.

The difference here is that `Scanner` works dynamically, whereas, something like an iterator works in a static context, and already has the values.